# return Unpickler(file).load() error while using pickle.load

Tags: python

I am using pickle to read a file. Below is the code

```
import pickle
fil = open("check", "rb")
res = pickle.load(fil)

print res

fil.close()
```

I am getting error as

```
  File "inter.txt", line 20, in <module>
    res = pickle.load(fil)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '{'
```

How i can read file with pickle

Comment: It seems like your `check` file is not a valid `pickle` file. Can you paste its content please?

Comment: What is valid pickle file. It is file having json format structure

Comment: @Nitesh Then you need to load it with `json.load`, not the pickle module.

Comment: Cannot we read all files using pickle? Are there any specific pickle files which it can read?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called `pickle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a `JSON` file with [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

[Pickle's format is Python specific](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format), not `JSON`.

Here is the same `{'foo': 'bar'}` dict dumped with `pickle` and `json`:

*Pickle*:

```
(dp0
S'foo'
p1
S'bar'
p2
s.
```

*JSON*:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

As you can see, `pickle`'s serialization is really not same as `JSON` format.

---

Uses `json.load(filehandler)` instead.